# How to open and transpose list in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb, transpose

I have a given dataframe:

| id | list*ofnumbers* |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | [1, 2, 5, 6, 7] |
| 5 | [1, 2, 13, 51, 12] |

Where one column is just id, and the other one is list of number made like that which i got previously from JSON file, is there any way to get this into this format using only MySQL?

| id | list*of*numbers |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 |
| 2 | 5 |
| 2 | 6 |
| 2 | 7 |
| 5 | 1 |
| 5 | 2 |
| 5 | 13 |
| 5 | 51 |
| 5 | 12 |
|  |  |

I know it could be easily done using Python and pandas, but I only need to use MySQL in that case, and I do not really know how to transpose lists in MySQL like that

Comment: If you have the original `id` along with the array in the same json document, something using [json_table](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/json_table/) might be possible in MariaDB.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQL split values to multiple rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17942508/sql-split-values-to-multiple-rows)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [json_table()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-table-functions.html)

```
create table myTable(id int, listofnumbers varchar(200));
insert into myTable values(2,   '[1, 2, 5, 6, 7]');
insert into myTable values(5,   '[1, 2, 13, 51, 12]');
```

```
select t.id, j.listofnumbers
from myTable t
join json_table(
  t.listofnumbers,
  '$[*]' columns (listofnumbers varchar(50) path '$')
) j;
```

| id | listofnumbers |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 |
| 2 | 5 |
| 2 | 6 |
| 2 | 7 |
| 5 | 1 |
| 5 | 2 |
| 5 | 13 |
| 5 | 51 |
| 5 | 12 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/NsKG6a4F)

Answer (score 0):

@Ruslan Pylypiuk

Postgresql soultion:

```
select 
id,regexp_split_to_table(listofnumbers,',')
from test
```

Mysql soultion : refer [SQL split values to multiple rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17942508/sql-split-values-to-multiple-rows)